# Inline ajax's response fails in checking condition even though the condition is true

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I am using an inline jquery ajax to delete a list one by one. When giving an action to delete a list, the ajax will send some post data and the response is json encoded. Upon successful response, a pop up box will open in the first ajax success field asking for the username and password. Then an inline ajax will execute there, sending the pop up box's values along with the response from first ajax. I have given a condition in the inline ajax success field to validate the response for the second posted values. The response is coming true but the condition fails, i don't know why. Please refer the code...

```
$('.deleteButton').on('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'phpPage.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $(this).serialize() + "&del=del",
        success: function (d) {
            $(".popupContainer").show();
            var text = "Do you really want to delete the report dated:";
            $('#info').text(text);
            $('#delForm').on('submit', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'delRept.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: $(this).serialize() + "&vtime=" + d.vtime + "&vdate=" + d.vdate + "&delbox=delbox",
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data == 'string') {
                            $('#rrr').append("True : Delete it");
                        } else {
                            $('#rrr').append(data);
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Here it will execute the else condition even if the response is true. Please help me to find the mistake in the coding...

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you put a `console.log(data);` before `if(data == 'true'){` and check the browser console?

Comment: You are using true as a string with quotes in it. Make sure you need that or you are sending a boolean ?

Comment: I am just returning a string. I put true in this code for a better understanding

Comment: Do you have a `die();` at the end of your PHP code?

Comment: @Siguza : in the console it is showing the correct returned value. But here my problem is, the condition check is failing even if it is true; and Jared, there is no die() in my code

Comment: @Sajin But is it truly the value you check against? Not JSON-encoded? Not newline-terminated?

Comment: can you share the ajax response here ??

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. I just figured it out, Instead of returning a string I replaced it with boolean. Thanks to @zafar for noticing this :)

Comment: use console.log( $.type( data ) ) to check the type of value  returned and then use the condition accordingly

Comment: @Siguza I was just returning a string like echo "string"; . I do not know why does it failed in the condition check.

Comment: Thanks @sjain, vote up if it saved your time :)

Comment: I cannot.. I have less reputation :(